# How to load an random number in ["random number"] code

Tags: javascript, xml, random

Hi this is my cocde to load an xml file:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
 this.url = url;
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:\Documents and Settings\...books.xml"));

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(xmlData.author.text()[0]);
}
```

but I want to generate a random number in this line `trace(xmlData.author.text()[0]);`
so instead of [0] there needs to be an random number between the [ ]

Comment: Here is a reference implementation: http://xkcd.com/221/ :)

Comment: did you mean `actionscript`? (not that it matters... `Math.random() * N` should work in both).

Comment: @Emissary so I schould put it like this: trace(xmlData.author.text()[Math.random() * N]); ???

Comment: `N` representing your desired range of course - yes... well no, you should probably wrap it in `Math.floor()` too.  Also, [google that sh*t](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) =D  If it isn't obvious already you should be ensuring that your random number is in the bounds of your `xmlData.author.text()` array.

Comment: @Emissary so I schould put it like this: trace(xmlData.author.text()Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min););  ???

Comment: @Emissary but that doesn't work so I dont know how to put it together that is my whole question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuation from comments; you can't just copy and paste your way through a problem - you have to apply a little thought...

```js
// break down the problem, if this line returning 
// an array lets assign it to a variable.
var authorText = xmlData.author.text();

// random index should be within the bounds of the array length
var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * authorText.length );

// put it together
trace( authorText[random] );
```

Assuming the rest of your code is okay then this should work - here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3D3C/) in javascript though I suspect you are doing something in actionscript / flash (though they both conform to ECMAScript so it should work just the same).

Comment: thanks for the help this is what I needed, I'm glad you will help me and don't do what others do with a noob, you made me happy and get further in my project and that is something worth too I think. But I get undefined as I try the code my xml looks like this: see next comment

Comment: <Books>
<Book ISBN="0553212419">
<title>
Sherlock Holmes: Complete Novels and Stories, Vol 1
</title>
<author>Sir Arthur Conan Doyle</author>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="0743273567">
<title>The Great Gatsby</title>
<author>F. Scott Fitzgerald</author>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="0684826976">
<title>Undaunted Courage</title>
<author>Stephen E. Ambrose</author>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="0743203178">
<title>Nothing Like It In the World</title>
<author>Stephen E. Ambrose</author>
</Book>
</Books>

Comment: and sorry if I didn't mentioned I'm working in flash as3 and using an xml file

Comment: Flash isn't a strong point for me and I don't have an environment setup to run any tests.  You'd be better reposting your question tagged with `actionscript-3` - but be a little more specific as to what is undefined :)

Comment: this is the only thing what flash gives me as output: "undefined"

Comment: how are you running it, through a terminal?  Try putting a `trace("some string")` inside your `loadXML` function - does it print anything at all? if not then it's not getting there.  Are you sure it's loading the file correctly?  Your example specifies a full path on the file-system - where is your project loaded from? It may not have permission to access files outside of it's own root.  I can only really guess though - there isn't enough information to go on.

Comment: stop();
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
 
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.kirupa.com/net/files/sampleXML.xml"));

var authorText = xmlData.Book.author.text();
var random1 = Math.floor( Math.random() * authorText.length );

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
vraag.text=( authorText[random1] );
} this is the code what I'm using, it only gives Error #2007 at flash.text::TextField/set text()
 at xmlflashwerkt_fla::MainTimeline/LoadXML()

Comment: at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()